# Fetch deleted SVN repository from Jenkins Subversion plugin

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

I want to compile a branch that was deleted in SVN. It is still accessible from TortoiseSVN but only until the revision when it was deleted (i.e 999).

I want to compile it from Jenkins with the [Subversion plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin). I thought that setting the url and requesting a revision where the URL existed would work:

mySVNrepo/mydeletedbranch@998

That branch existed in revision 998.

However, I get an error

> ERROR: Failed to check out mySVNrepo/mydeletedbranch@998
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: 'mySVNrepo/mydeletedbranch' path not found: 404 Not Found (mySVNrepo)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLocationsImpl(DAVRepository.java:1105)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getLocations(SVNRepository.java:1094)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getLocations(SVNRepository.java:1522)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:207)
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:43)

How can I solve this?